# Cypher query resultset growing over subsequent runs?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm new to Neo4j CYPHER query language. I'm discovering it, while analyzing a graph of person to person relationships coming from a CRM system. I'm using Neo4j 2.1.2 Community Edition with Oracle Java JDK 1.7.0_45 on Windows 7 Enterprise, and interacting with Neo4j thru the web interface.

One thing puzzles me: I noticed that the resultset of some of my queries do grow over time, that is, if I run the same query after having used the database for quite a long time (1 or 2 hours later), I get a bit more results the second time -- having not updated, deleted or added anything to the database.

Is that possible? Are there special cases where it could happen? I would expect the database results to be consistent over time, as long as there is no change to the database.

I feel it is, as if the database was growing its indexes over time in the background, and if the query results were depending on the database engine's ability to reach more nodes and relationships thru the grown indexes. Could it be a memory or index configuration issue? Or did I possibly got to much coffee? Alas, it is not easily reproductible.

Sample query:

```
MATCH (pf:Portfolio)<-[:withRelation]-(p1:Partner)-[:JOINTACC]->(p2:Partner)
WHERE (pf.dateBoucl = '') AND (pf.catClient = 'NO')
      AND NOT (p2)-[:relTo]->(:Partner)
MATCH (p1)-[r]->(p3:Partner)
      WHERE NOT (p3)-[:relTo]->(:Partner)
        AND NOT TYPE( r) IN [ 'relTo', 'ADRESSAT', 'MEMBER']
WITH pf, p1, p2, COLLECT( TYPE( r)) AS types
        WHERE ALL( t IN types WHERE t = 'JOINTACC')
RETURN pf.catClient, pf.natureTitulaire, COUNT( DISTINCT pf);
```

At first I got 98 results. When running it 2 hours later, I get 103 results, and then it seems stable for subsequent runs. And I'm pretty sure I did not change the database contents.

Any hints very appreciated! Kind regards

---

Schema looks like this:

```
:schema

Indexes
  ON :Country(ID)          ONLINE (for uniqueness constraint) 
  ON :Partner(partnerID)   ONLINE (for uniqueness constraint) 
  ON :Portfolio(partnerID) ONLINE                             
  ON :Portfolio(noCli)     ONLINE                             
  ON :Portfolio(noDos)     ONLINE                             

Constraints
  ON (partner:Partner) ASSERT partner.partnerID IS UNIQUE
  ON (country:Country) ASSERT country.ID IS UNIQUE
```

Comment: What indexes are you using?  (Legacy lucene indexes and new indexes).  What constraints are you using?  How many results do you expect this query to return?   When/how was the data loaded?

Comment: I believe I'm using the new indexes, which I set up with instructions such as `CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (pa:Partner) ASSERT pa.partnerID IS UNIQUE`. But the indexes I created are probably not involved in the execution, as I created none on the relationships.

The data was loaded with `LOAD CSV FROM … MERGE … CREATE (nodes)… CREATE (rels)…`. I don't know how much results there should exactly be, as this is what I'm trying to figure out with that query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dump / download your query results from both runs and do a diff on them. Then you see what differs and you can investigate where it came from.

Perhaps you also should update to 2.1.3 which has one caching problem resolved that could be related to this.

Comment: Many thanks for the insight. I had indeed the feeling that something with a cache, or an index growing over time, was involved. So may be I did hit that caching problem.

Comment: Thanks also for the suggestion to diff the results. I tried to reproduce the problem, and replayed all queries against Neo4j version 2.1.2 a few times, however could not reproduce the issue I observed.

Yet I upgraded to 2.1.3 today as you suggested -- where I also immediately get the expected results. Kind regards.